# Formatting numbers with prohibited characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

Formatting a value to display units adds clarity while retaining the numerical value in the cell. This can be done using:

`=TEXT(1000,"#,### kW")`

or via the formatting dialog: *Format Cells > Number > Category Custom*

But some characters are not allowed by either method. How can this be done for units like "kWh" or "kWh/yr" without converting the value to a text type and thereby preventing the value from being used in a calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either enclose your string within quotes, or "escape" each character

eg:  `#,### \k\W\h`

or:  `#,### "kWh"`

*(works either as a custom number format, or as the format argument for the `TEXT` function)*

**EDIT:** Because of the question from @SOlsen, I will add that if you use the quoted format within the text function, you will need to double-up on the included quotes.

Comment: ...yes, that works for a custom number format (which is what I would recommend), but how would that work as part of the text() function?  The text function won't accept the argument as you presented it (whole format argument needs to be in quotes).  You can enter it as =text(1,000, "#,### kWh"), but as the OP noted, the result is considered text and not numeric as they desired.  I'm just wondering if I'm missing something I didn't know about.

Comment: @SOlson Yes, you are missing something.  To use "quotes with quotes" you "double-up" (routine in Excel so I neglected to mention it).:  `=TEXT(1000,"#,### ""kWh""")` and the escaping method doesn't even require included quotes: `=TEXT(1000,"#,### \k\W\h")`  I will add that caveat to my answer.

Comment: yes that displays it with kWh...but as text. Let's say you put that in cell A1, then in cell B1 you try to multiply that by 2...you get a #VALUE! error because it's considered text (as verified by entering ```=istext(A1)``` in cell B1).  So, that's what I was saying wouldn't meet the OP requirement of being able to use the numeric value in a calculation...it would just be a text value and you'd have to type cast it with something like ```=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))``` as part of calculations after that point.

Comment: @SOlson Good point. I suppose the only logical output of the `=TEXT()` would be a text type. Even `=TEXT(1000,"#,###")` is text.I guess I've overlooked this in the past because, without any additional formatting, Excel is still able to infer the numerical value and allow it to be used in a calculation.

Comment: @SOlson  I don't understand the point you are trying to make.  Of course, if you wanted it as a number, you would use the format as a custom number format (as the OP requested).  And if you wanted it as text (say as part of a longer string where you referenced that cell), you would use the `TEXT` function. That's pretty basic use of Excel.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, sorry I didn't mean to upset you.  You are right, that's pretty basic Excel usage.  Since there was no caveat in your answer, I thought maybe you were saying that the usage of the ```text``` function would also meet the OP requirements so I thought it was a new trick I could learn.  I apologize for trying to figure out it that was the case or not.