# Using TEXT() with escaped characters in number formatting leads to #VALUE! error when trying to calculate with the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, numbers, escaping

Suppose that cell `A1` contains the value `10` and the formula in `B1` is `=TEXT(A1 * 2, "#,##0.00 $\/\u\n\i\t")`. Then, the result of `B1` is properly displayed as `20.00 $/unit`.

Writing `=B1 * 3` into cell `C1`, however, leads to a `#VALUE!` error.

Why is that and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the value in `B1` is now interpreted as text, the `#VALUE!` error occurs. Writing `=VALUE(LEFT(B1, FIND(" ", B1)))` instead gives back a proper result in `C1`.

This solution was inspired by [S Olson’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225327/s-olson) second comment that was posted to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63402198/8713892).

Comment: Number formatting should be applied to `A1` so that the underlying value is still a number. Then you don't have to use `TEXT` at all.

Comment: This is just an example. How can I deal with circumstances in which only `B1` and `C1` exist given that the formula in `B1` is more complex because it should, for example, give back a result that is `x $/unit` in one case and `y $/m²` in another? How can I then calculate with such a number in `C1`?

Comment: In that case you'd definitely need `TEXT` but then your question isn't representative of that situation.